# Acceder a jQuery localmente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual accedo a unas librerías:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

He intentando descargar las paginas de los link y acceder localmente de la siguiente forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="files/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="files/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Usando el primer código funciona perfectamente, pero quiero ejecutar el código en un servidor offline de una LAN, como debería acceder a los archivos?

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes escrito, necesitas una carpeta `files`a la misma altura que el HTML que estás cargando. Dentro de esa carpeta deberán is los ficheros .js

Comment: @PabloLozano Así lo tengo.

Comment: Finalmente lo he arreglado únicamente quitando el `crossorigin`.

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate de tener una carpeta con el nombre files (según el código que escribes). Aunque es posible que tu página no localice los archivos, depende de donde las pongas.
Para asegurarte:
Coloca la carpeta files en el **directorio raíz** de tu sitio local
En los links a los css y js asegúrate de iniciarlos con /
El código te quedará así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/files/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="/files/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

De esta manera cualquier página los debe encontrar.
Si qieres asegurarte en plan paranóico ;), puede poner la dirección absoluta de los ficheros http://localhost/file/jquery.min.js suponiendo que tu servidor local es localhost. Pero vamos que con la primera solución te debe funcionar todo en local sin mayor problema.

Comment: La sugerencia de añadir un `/` no arregla el problema. Debe ejecutarse sobre un servidor  o localmente también sirve? Lo digo porque estoy accediendo con una ruta como la siguiente `file:///C:/Users/`

Comment: Con protocolo file también debe funcionar, pero entonces pon en el link el protocolo completo no solo /file, sino con file:///C:  seguido de todo el path hasta tus archivos
De todas maneras  yo te aconsejaría que montaras un servidor local. Sobre todo si estas trabajano o aprendiendo desarrollo web.